# How to hide DataTables buttons(pdf, copy, excel, print) using if condition

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

Am facing issue with show and hide buttons of Jquery Datatables with and if condition.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGXBj.png)

I want to hide Copy, PDF, Excel, Print buttons based on the bellow condition

```
$('#students').DataTable({
    role_id: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('role_id'); ?>',
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    // scrollX: true,
    if (role_id = 2) { 
    // show buttons 
        buttons: [
            // 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            {extend: "excel", className: "buttonsToHide"},
            {extend: "pdf", className: "buttonsToHide"},
            {extend: "print", className: "buttonsToHide"}
        ]
    } else {
        // hide buttons
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you

```php
<?php if($role_id == 1) { ?>
// add the html of your buttons here
<?php } ?>
```